# Firebase push notification with data message or notification message

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a push notification to the user which does two things:

- inform the user a new file is available
- automatically download the file in the background so that it is available when the user opens the app

For the first use case I can use a Notification Message and for the second a Data Message. But what is the best approach to combine both use cases?

Idea 1:
I could send two different messages for each use case?

Idea 2:
I use a Data Message and when the app receives the message the app takes care of showing a notification.

Which one should I prefer or is there a better approach?

Comment: I think second idea is better,

Comment: I think using Data Message is better, since you can handle both, showing notification and downloading file , with ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options):

> With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:
>
> - Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
> - Data messages, which are handled by the client app.

It sounds like what you're doing is not a "display message".  You're just trying to tell your app to do something.

Also, you should know that notification messages can't be directly handled by the app when it's in the background.  In that case, FCM will simply show the notification in the notification tray.